# How to Avoid Window Download Popup in Firefox use Java selenium? i need download automatically with out ask popup?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

*My code is  here:-*

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.sample-videos.com/");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sample-mp4-video']/table/tbody/tr[0]/td[4]")).click();
```

Objective is to handle windows popup so that the download file is saved to local drive.

Is there any way to automate using selenium

Answer (score 5):

You can automatically download a file by customising the preferences. You need to define the download folder in `browser.download.dir` and the MIME type of the file that will be downloaded (`video/mp4` in your example). Note that the MIME type is the `Content-Type` header returned in the response of the request.

Here is a working example with the page from your post:

```java
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Temp");  // folder
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "video/mp4");  // MIME type
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);  // disable the built-in viewer
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("http://www.sample-videos.com/");

// click on the link "10 mp4 720x480"
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td='10'][td='mp4'][td='720x480']//a")).click();
```

Comment: @Florent B. This method is different one compare to others. Creating a FIrefox profile and adding it to Capabilities. Much useful to me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need use Firefox profiling to overcome from this issue:-

```
    FirefoxProfile pro=new FirefoxProfile();

    pro.setPreference("browser.downLoad.folderList", 0);

    pro.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "Applications/zip");

    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(pro);
```

browser.download.folderList controls the default folder to download a file to. 0 indicates the Desktop; 1 indicates the systems default downloads location; 2 indicates a custom folder.
browser.download.dir holds the custom destination folder for
downloading. It is activated if browser.download.folderList has been set to 2.
browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk stores a comma-separated list of MIME types to save to disk without asking what to use to open the file.
Below code for chrome multiple download option:-

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("download.default_directory", getClass().getResource("/data/input").toString().replace("%20", " ").replace("file:","").replaceFirst("/", ""));
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

options.addArguments("--test-type");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

For IE Refer :-

http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/
You can also use Robot class of java but it can lock your screen for while

You need to use ROBOT class for firing an ENTER Action event. In java if you want to fire any event you have to use Robot class for typing using programatically or firing events like ENTER and ESCAPE.

```
// Create object of Robot class
Robot object=new Robot();

// Press Enter
object.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

// Release Enter
object.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Please get back to me if still facing issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a Firefox profile:

```
public class FileDownloadExample 
{
    public static String downloadPath = "D:\\seleniumdownloads";
    @Test
    public void testDownload() throws Exception 
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverProfile());   
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://URL");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("test.xls")).click();
    }

    public static FirefoxProfile FirefoxDriverProfile() throws Exception 
    {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadPath);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
                "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);
        return profile;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and try. It will download automaticallly.

```
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.sample-videos.com/");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  Thread.sleep(5000L);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sample-mp4-video']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/a")).click();
  Thread.sleep(5000L);
  Robot robot=new Robot();
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Reply to me for further query.
Happy learning. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved by using the below code snippet

```
 System.setProperty(GEKO_DRIVER, FIREFOX_DRIVER_LOCATION);
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
 FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
 profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
 profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
 profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
      "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
 profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
"text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
 profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
 profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
 profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
 profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
 profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
 profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);
 options.setProfile(profile);
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```